# buid qt5.4.1 on centos5.5 error

Tags: linux, compile, qt

I'm ready build Qt5.4.1 on Centos5.5,
according this https://kate-editor.org/2014/12/22/qt-5-4-on-red-hat-enterprise-5/。

and now i got some problem when build qt src。
when i do the make command, it say:

- g++: error: LIBS: No such file or directory
- g++: error: =: No such file or directory

but i found the "LIBS" in qtbase/src/tools/moc/Makefile

- LIBS          = $(SUBLIBS)
  -L/home/chenc/tmp/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.4.1/qtbase/lib -lQt5Bootstrap -lpthread

is that qmake's problem? please help me, thank you.

Comment: DONE!  I should use gmake instead of make

Answer (score 0):

- THE DETAIL LOG:
- cd tools/moc/ && ( test -e Makefile ||
  /home/chenc/tmp/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.4.1/qtbase/bin/qmake
  /home/chenc/tmp/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.4.1/qtbase/src/tools/moc/moc.pro
  -o Makefile ) && make -f Makefile
- make[3]: Entering directory
  `/home/chenc/tmp/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.4.1/qtbase/src/tools/moc'
- g++ -Wl,--gc-sections -Wl,-O1 -fuse-ld=gold
  -Wl,-rpath,/home/chenc/tmp/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.4.1/qtbase/src/tools/moc/\
  -Wl,-rpath,/home/chenc/tmp/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.4.1/qtbase/src/tools/moc/
  LIBS          = 
  -L/home/chenc/tmp/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.4.1/qtbase/lib -lQt5Bootstrap -lpthread -o ../../../bin/moc .obj/moc.o .obj/preprocessor.o .obj/generator.o .obj/parser.o .obj/token.o
  .obj/main.o
- g++: error: LIBS: No such file or directory
- g++: error: =: No such file or directory